# Generates dynamic paths from GraphQL API in Nextjs

Tags: typescript, next.js, graphql

I have a page list of projects, i want to be able to visit the page of a single project but i keep getting 404 page instead.

I've tried to fetching the data using simple Fetch and the ApolloClient but they seems to keep showing me the same bug.

Sometimes it shows this error :'could not load scripts from page [].js' and sometimes other errors

This is the folder structure of the pages

[image: This is the folder structure of the pages]

and this is my code for the getStaticProps and the getStaticPaths:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const { projectId } = params

    const result = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DRUPAL_BASE_URL}/graphql`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                // Authorization: `Bearer`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: `
                     query GetProject($path: String!) {
                        nodeArticles(where: {path: $path},limit: 1) {
                            nodes {
                                title
                                body {
                                    value:processed
                                }
                                image {
                                    url
                                }
                                path
                            }
                        }
                    }
                `,
                variables: {
                    path: projectId,
                },
            }),
        },
    );

    if (!result.ok) {
        console.error(result);
        return {};
    }

    const { data } = await result.json();

    const [ProjectData] = data.nodeArticles.nodes;

    return {
        props: { data: ProjectData || null },
    };

}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const result = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DRUPAL_BASE_URL}/graphql`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: `
                    {
                    nodeArticles(first: 100) {
                        nodes {
                                path
                            }
                        }
                    }
                `,
            }),
        },
    );

    if (!result.ok) {
        console.error(result);
        return {};
    }
    const { data } = await result.json();

    const projects = data.nodeArticles.nodes;

    const pagesPaths = projects.map(({ path }) => {
        return {
            params: { projectId: path },
        };
    });


    return {
        paths: pagesPaths || [],
        fallback: false,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pages in next.js should be in 'page' directory.
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages

Maybe some problems in your code still, but not enough presenation

Comment: They are inside the 'Pages' folder

Comment: maybe there are incorrect data in pagesPaths. Make representation at code sandbox, right now not enough information to understand this problem